# httplib2 API is different when installed from source or as RPM?

Tags: python, https, installation, redhat, httplib2

Boy, is this frustrating...

I installed the `httplib2` by downloading the .tar.gz package from the [site](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) on my CentOS development VM. After spending 1/2 day to get it do two-way ssl authentication, I install the `python26-httplib2.noarch` on the target RHEL 5.7 machine. Suddenly the code does not run as the class constructor is different!

The [official documentation](http://httplib2.googlecode.com/hg/doc/html/libhttplib2.html#http-objects) defines the `Http` class as follows:

> class httplib2.Http([cache=None][, timeout=None][, proxy_info=None][,
>   ca_certs=None][, disable_ssl_certificate_validation=False])

My code that uses the tar installation indeed does this, and it works:

```
client = httplib2.Http(ca_certs='/path-to/ca.cert')
```

However, the `ca_cert` parameter is not recognized in the RPM installation. Looking in the lib, I indeed see the following:

```
class Http(object):

    def __init__(self, cache=None, timeout=None, proxy_info=None):
```

i.e. totally different parameter list.

Is there any explanation for this?

PS. Sorry if I sound furious - I am. It's 8pm and I hoped to check in the code today...
PPS. Python 2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess: different httplib2 versions. As far as I understand from a quick glance at the change log and code, `ca_certs` supports SSL server certificate validation, which has been added in httplib2 0.7.0. Is it possible that the httplib2 version coming from RPM is older than that? What does `print httplib2.__version__` show?

As a workaround, I would suggest not to install Python libraries from tar.gz files or from Red Hat packages; use [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) instead, possibly with a requirement file where you can specify the exact version number (or even a lower-bound one) of each external library you need for your program to run.

Comment: sounds plausible - the working version is indeed 0.7, and the rpm (according to the `yum info` is 0.6. But - the documentation specifies 0.4, so I assumed the API is the same for 0.4 and above...

Comment: as for installing with pip - we build our install as an rpm (we target RHEL only) specifying external dependencies, so the installation at user's site would bring the required packages from public repositories. Using pip would require an additional mechanism or pre-requisites; not sure it will be approved.

Comment: @davka would it be feasible, in your scenario, to directly include the right version of httplib2 in your source code instead of specifying it as an external dependency?

Comment: interesting thought, I'll check. BTW, where do you see the change log?

Comment: thanks. I see that rpms with 0.7 exist for different distros but not for RHEL 5. But since it's a noarch lib, does the distribution matters? Thanks a lot for your help BTW

Comment: @davka I can't really say, lacking any experience on the nuisance of package management for Linux distributions. Maybe that's a topic for a new StackOverlow (or similar site) question.